# Obtener valores de columnas dinamicas para facturacion

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos estoy diseñando una factura con columnas y filas dinámicas, funciona de maravilla pero me hace falta que calcule el precio de todos los productos que se hayan elegido (dinámicamente) y ponga el total en un input "subtotal" pero al ser dinámicos no se como podría acceder a sus valores. Funciona así: Se selecciona el producto y la cantidad y cuando se le da en añadir el producto se agrega al cuerpo de la factura dinámicamente con sus precios. Al ultimo ya tengo listo y funcionando los inputs de total e IVA, solo el subtotal debería recibir el valor para que los otros dos inputs trabajen y por el momento funciona si se le escribe manualmente. Espero que me haya explicado bien. Si necesitan algún detalle que me falto agregar me hacen saber.

```
 <tbody id="tbody">
      <!-- Aqui se agregan las columnas y filas dinamicas !-->
 </tbody>

 <tfoot>

     <div class="form-group col-md-2">

        <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>SUBTOTAL</b></label>
         <input type="text" id="subtotal"class="form-control" onchange="calcularFactura(); calculoIva();" >


     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
         <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>IVA (12%)</b></label>
         <input type="text" id="iva" class="form-control" disabled>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
         <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>TOTAL</b></label>
         <input id="totalfact" type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>

 </tfoot>
```

Js

```
const rediseñotabla = () => {
        tbody.innerHTML = ""; 
        arregloDatos.forEach((datos) => { 
            let fila = document.createElement("tr");
            fila.innerHTML =
                `<input id ="id" type="hidden" value ="${datos.id}">
                 <td >${datos.producto}</td> 
                 <td >${datos.descripcion}</td> 
                 <td >${datos.cant}</td> 
                 <td >$ ${datos.pUnit }</td> 
                 <td class="precioTotal"> ${datos.pTotal}</td>`;
    formDatos.onsubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const objDatos = {
            id: selectProduct.value,
            producto: selectProduct.value = ($('select[id="selectProduct"] option:selected').text()),
            descripcion: selectDescripcion.textContent,
            cant: inputCantidad.value,
    
            pUnit: inputunitario.textContent,
            pTotal: inputtotal.value,
    
    
        };
        
    
        agregarDatos(objDatos);
    
    
        rediseñotabla();
    };

function calculoIva() {

    var tasaIva = 12;
    var monto = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
    var IVATotal = (monto * tasaIva) / 100;
    iva.value = IVATotal.toFixed(2);
    const a = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("iva").value;
    totalfact.value = ((a - b).toFixed(2));
};

const calcularTotal = () => {
    const cantidad = +inputCantidad.value;
    const pUnit = +inputunitario.value;
    const total = cantidad * pUnit;
    inputtotal.value = total.toFixed(2); //agregat dos valores decimales 
};


function calcularFactura() {

    var sum = 0;
    $('.precioTotal').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $('#subtotal').val(sum.toFixed(2));

    console.log(sum);
}
```

Edit:

Estoy cerca de lograrlo, implemente la funcion calcularFactura y funciona pero no lleva el valor de la suma automaticamente a mi input, tengo que escribir algo en el input para que reemplace el valor con la suma y ahi si funciona, pero como dije necesito que lo lleve automaticamente apenas se agreguen los productos :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Faltan muchas cosas para conseguir un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Así poco te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Estás repitiendo ID y [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), de lo contrario, se va a obtener solo uno. Deberías usar clases y recorrer dentro de un ciclo para calcular cada fila.

Comment: @Triby lo podria recorrer con un for? Y para seleccionar las clases es con document.querySelectorAll?